# Fody plugin Validar fails. Could not load type 'Validar.ValidationTemplateAttribute' from assembly mscorlib

Tags: .net, wpf, validation, fody, fody-validar

I'm trying to use [Validar](https://github.com/Fody/Validar) to inject validation in my classes. My solution consists of multiple (5 for now, can become more in the future) projects in which I want to inject the validation. So I defined my `ValidationTemplate` class in one of them and placed the `ValidationTemplateAttribute` in every assembly like this:

```cs
using Validar;

[assembly: ValidationTemplate(typeof(IMS.General.Validation.ValidationTemplate))]
```

When I build I receive an error which I do not understand, but stops me from going further:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WinFx.targets(268,9):
>   error MC1000: Unknown build error, 'Could not load type
>   'Validar.ValidationTemplateAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.'

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 professional update 4 and the target framework is .Net framework 4.5

If it is of any use for the question my implementation of the `ValidationTemplate` looks like:

```cs
namespace IMS.General.Validation
{
    public class ValidationTemplate : INotifyDataErrorInfo
    {
        private readonly INotifyPropertyChanged target;
        private readonly ValidationContext validationContext;
        private readonly List<ValidationResult> validationResults;

        public ValidationTemplate(INotifyPropertyChanged target)
        {
            this.target = target;
            this.validationContext = new ValidationContext(target, null, null);
            this.validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
            Validator.TryValidateObject(this.target, this.validationContext,
                       this.validationResults, true);
            target.PropertyChanged += Validate;
        }

        private void Validate(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.validationResults.Clear();
            Validator.TryValidateObject(this.target, this.validationContext, 
                 this.validationResults, true);
            var hashSet = new HashSet<string>(
                 this.validationResults.SelectMany(x => x.MemberNames));

            foreach (var error in hashSet)
            {
                this.ErrorsChanged(this, 
                        new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(error));
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
        {
            return this.validationResults
                         .Where(x => x.MemberNames.Contains(propertyName))
                         .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);
        }

        public bool HasErrors
        {
            get { return this.validationResults.Count > 0; }
        }

        public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> 
                ErrorsChanged = (s, e) => { };
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I solve this issue?

**Edit:**
Come on guys!! Is there really nobody who can help me with this. Should I make a test solution to show the problem? Please advise! I'm really in need of a solution! Fody normally works great and saves me a lot of work while keeping my classes nice and clean!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After direct contact with the programmer of Validar he found that different versions of .Net framework treat [importing into modules](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/wiki/Importing) differently. He fixed the issues on released **version 1.4.6**. This fixes the problem.

**So my advice:** Use Fody and Validar. It works great, has good support and keeps your code clean while having beautiful validation in your WPF application (or any other framework using `INotifyDataErrorInfo`).